# how to join to files with unique identifiers

Tags: python, pandas

I can join the files based on integer values,
but I can't join the columns based on string.

import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel(r'sample.xlsx')

df2=pd.read_excel(r'sample2.xlsx')

inner = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id'], how='left')

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
inner = df1.merge(df2)
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).